# Place icon after a line with text-overflow ellipsis

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with text-overflow: ellipsis. I want to place an icon after the 3 dots, but the icon always appears on the next line (because of the display: block property). Is there any way to display the line like this?

[image]

My example [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/27rov6qn/) and the css:

```
.title {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `inline-block` instead and set the icon to `position: absolute` in order to always have it place where the last `span` ends.

```
.title {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
}

.fa {
  position: absolute;
}
```

See here:
https://jsfiddle.net/27rov6qn/1/

Answer (score 4):

The problem with the above approaches is that when the text is shortened it leaves the icon at the end of the text span.

Setting a max-width here would add to the approaches mentioned above.

```
.title {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Wrap it all in another `span` and use `inline-block` instead of `block`

```css
.title {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<span>
  <span class="title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.</span>

<i class="fa fa-home fa-fw"></i>

</span>
```

Comment: How to achieve the same but with 2 lines? I added   
display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
   -moz-box-orient: vertical;
but it is not working @Paulie_D

Answer (score 0):

```
Separate it in container and row
```

```css
div.container {
    width:170px;
}

div.icon, div.text {
    padding-right:5px;
}

div.icon {
    float:right;
}

div.row, div.text {
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
}

div.row {
    display:inline-block;
    max-width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="icon">[icon]</div>
            <div class="text">Long text long text long text long text</div>
        </div>
</div>
```