# Place icon at the end of a truncated multiline text without breaking into new line

Tags: javascript, css

I have a requirement where I need to display two lines of text followed by an icon (rendered via img tag). If the text length exceeds two lines, need to show ellipsis. But the icon should be inline with the text, and should not be clipped when text length increases.

It should be something like

```
A lengthy text that
spans two lin..
```

Assume the *emoji* to be an `img` tag

[Place icon after a line with text-overflow ellipsis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35043062/place-icon-after-a-line-with-text-overflow-ellipsis)

For a single line text, this can be done with inline-block as  suggested by answers in the above stack overflow. But for a multiline text, if I add this, it doesn't work.

```
display: -webkit-box;
-webkit-line-clamp: 2;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
-moz-box-orient: vertical;
```

https://codepen.io/praneethack/pen/LYxxPGN

Edit: Have modified codepen code to have img tag instead of font icon

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
.title {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  /*white-space: nowrap;*/
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -moz-box-orient: vertical;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  font-size: 1em; /* Set a font size */
  max-height: calc(2em + 5px); /* Set height for twice the font size plus some padding */
}
```

I removed the white space value and added a font size of 1em.

Then I set a max height of 2em that will show maximum of two rows.

**EDIT** Completely skipped the whole image issue.

Here's an updated answer

```css
.title {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -moz-box-orient: vertical;
  font-size: 1em;
  max-height: calc(2em + 5px);
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}

.icon {
  width: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<span>
  <span class="title">
<img class="icon" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSBdJ13-QNu7aJefmbaMMuY6ngaEbGWXaf6Ag&usqp=CAU"/>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.</span>
</span>
```

The image tag is inside the span. Note that it has to be before the text.

Comment: This keeps the icon always fixed at right side.. if the text is smaller, it will still keep the icon at right most

Comment: Maybe there's a need for JS code. This might help [link](https://css-tricks.com/line-clampin/)

Answer (score 0):

#### Two (identical) elements are required for this effect:

the first element (icon) is placed as the first child of the text container, and it is only visible while the text is being truncated, while the 2nd element (same icon) is placed at the end, so obviously it will not be shown if the text is truncated (doesn't fit its container's height).

Using javascript to detect when the text is being truncated, the first icon element is being hidden if the text fits in the container and is not truncated.

It's important to note a `--line-clamp` CSS variable is used for both the `line-clamp` property value and the `::before` pseudo-element, because that "fake" floated element is what's "pushing" the first icon element to the bottom to appear at the end of the text (when truncated)

**This example allows horizonal resizing:**

```js
function isTextTruncated( elm ){ 
  const truncated = elm.scrollHeight > elm.clientHeight
  elm.classList.toggle('truncated', truncated)
}

// observe resize
const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver(m => isTextTruncated(m[0].target))

resizeObserver.observe(document.querySelector('p'), { attributes: true })
```

```css
p {
  --line-clamp: 4;
  
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: var(--line-clamp);
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  
  width: clamp(300px, 50%, 900px);
  resize: horizontal;
  overflow: hidden;
}

p::before {
  content: '';
  float: right;
  height: calc((var(--line-clamp) - 1) * 1lh);
}

p .icon:first-child {
  clear: both;
  float: right;
}

/* 
  no need to render the "show more" link if 
  the text is fully-visible and not truncated
*/
p:not(.truncated) .icon:first-child {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span class='icon'></span>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, 
  sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
  Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris 
  nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in 
  reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
  <span class='icon'></span>
</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to place an icon near ellipsis using `:before`:

```css
.foo {
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-box;
  max-width: 200px;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 4;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: black;
}


.foo:after {
  content: "... \f015";
  display: inline-block;
  font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
  font-size: inherit;
  text-rendering: auto;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  position: absolute;
  top: 88%;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0 2px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="foo">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.</div>
```